# What's up with the autoplay videos on Careers ads?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, videos

[This job listing](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/82098/dba-ninja-dailymotion) has an obnoxious video (with sound obviously) that autoplays as soon as the page loads. Not surprising when you see who their parent company is, but why is this allowed here ?

Screenshot of the disaster :

[image: screenshot]

The video is included in an `iframe`, why is this even possible ? Also the fact that the iframe is completely seamless (as you see above) makes abuse possible, like phishing (I'm not sure if creating some fake documents and obtaining a credit card anonymously is worth the hassle for some SE credentials, but it's definitely possible)...

Comment: I am not sure but adblock does the trick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually a video that the company has in the gallery of their company page. We control the iframe and it is limited to three video providers; YouTube, Vimeo and DailyMotion so the possibility of abuse is low to non-existent.

Our embed URL mistakenly had the autoplay option set which meant the video autoplays when you browse to the company page (or any job listings). Oops!

I've just pushed a fix to prod.

Comment: I think he means it's possible to steal cookies, not related to video, in the "possible abuse" statement. Anyhow, changed to [tag:bug] so it can be properly "fixed". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually no, I thought it was possible to make the iframe link to an arbitrary page and not just to whitelisted video sites.

Comment: @AndréDaniel oh, so guess  that is now settled as well? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, cf the status-completed tag.

Comment: Off topic, but curious to know, have you switched the job search over to Elastic search already?

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're running a split test at the moment to make sure there are no regressions in the click-through and application funnels. So soon, hopefully :)